# Slow DotNetCore 2.0 MVC after publish to IIS

Tags: performance, iis, model-view-controller, iis-7, .net-core

I have a Web Site that consumes two MVC web service.  The entire project, both services and the web site were developed with dotnetCore 2.0 MVC and Angular

I am using VSCode for development.  When I run in the VS Code debugger - (I guess that is Kestral?) Everything is great.  The Web Site (AngularJS) calls to Service A, Service A makes a bunch of calls to Service B and everything is very snappy an responsive.

OK. Now I do "dotnet publish" and move the output to be hosted in IIS.  Everything works the calls all execute successfully.  However, the calls from Service A to service B take several seconds each.  Where in the DEV server they take just a few milliseconds on the PROD Server the same call takes several seconds.

If I call from the web site to the Service B the response is as expected - very snappy.

So, to summarize
- Service A calling Service B on a DEV server with VSCODE debugger running is very fast
- Service A calling Service B on a PROD server with a Published version of the project running behind IIS very slow
- Calling AJAX directly to service B is working great even on the Published IIS version.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this.  Or even where I could start to debug the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you hosting the two services inside the same IIS web site? or application pool?

Comment: Yes.  On the same web server.

I have tried with same app pool and different app pools.  Same result.